# What scales can you get modes from?

Tags: theory, scales, modes

I know the modes from the major scale pretty well, and I've come to know that other scales like the melodic minor scales also has modes. So my question is, what other scales can modes be based off of besides the major scale? Or is it just that modes can be based off of the scales major, minor, harmonic minor, melodic minor, harmonic major, etc.. A list if possible would be good. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can have modes off every scale. To simplify what a mode is, try to think of it as a different note to start each scale. Even if you don't know the notes/name of some mode, just play the notes of the scale you want and each time start from a different note of the scale.

[**Here**](http://www2.siba.fi/muste1/index.php?id=79&la=en) is a list of the modes from the Melodic Minor scale:
[image]

Comment: This is exactly right. I'd just add that when people say "the modes" they usually mean the modes of the major scale.

Comment: Yep; "rotations" of scales is the general term for such "modes" of all scale types. "Rotations" thus indicates that you "rotate" the scale to begin on a pitch other than tonic.

Comment: All good stuff - but should the 2nd be Phrygian *natural* 6, and the 6th Locrian *natural* 2?

Comment: You can even theoretically get modes of scales like the whole tone scale and the chromatic scale this way--although modes of those scales sound just like transposed versions of the original, so they're pretty boring.

Comment: @Tim, writing these as ♯6 and ♯2 is a convention that seems to have some logic and precedence. `Phrygian ♯6` is a way of saying "the sixth tone of *this* scale is a half step above the sixth tone of the normal Phrygian scale." I don't know whether one is more accepted than the other--I'm used to seeing like you, I'm used to seeing the ♮ symbol, like you.

Comment: Only with some scales such as the whole-tone scale you don't get more than one mode out of them because all the steps are the same size. But that's kind of a fringe case. (And generally, if the pattern of steps repeats, there may be fewer modes than steps - half the number, third... you get the idea.)

Answer (score 6):

You're exactly right that modes can be created from virtually any scale. Below, I've included the modes of harmonic minor, melodic minor, harmonic major, and major (which you already know).

**Modes of Harmonic Minor Scale**

1. Harmonic Minor: `1 2 ♭3 4 5 ♭6 7`
2. Locrian ♮6: `1 ♭2 ♭3 4 ♭5 6 ♭7`
3. Ionian ♯5: `1 2 3 4 ♯5 6 7`
4. Dorian ♯4: `1 2 ♭3 ♯4 5 6 ♭7`
5. Phrygian major: `1 ♭2 3 4 5 ♭6 ♭7`
6. Lydian ♯2: `1 ♯2 3 ♯4 5 6 7`
7. Altered ♭♭7: `1 ♭2 ♭3 ♭4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭♭7`

**Modes of Melodic Minor Scale**

1. Melodic Minor: `1 2 ♭3 4 5 6 7`
2. Phrygian ♮6: `1 ♭2 ♭3 4 5 6 ♭7`
3. Lydian Augmented: `1 2 3 ♯4 ♯5 6 7`
4. Lydian Dominant: `1 2 3 ♯4 5 6 ♭7`
5. Mixolydian ♭6: `1 2 3 4 5 ♭6 ♭7`
6. Locrian ♮2: `1 2 ♭3 4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭7`
7. Altered Scale: `1 ♭2 ♭3 ♭4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭7`

**Modes of Harmonic Major Scale**

1. Harmonic Major: `1 2 3 4 5 ♭6 7`
2. Dorian ♭5: `1 2 ♭3 4 ♭5 6 ♭7`
3. Phrygian ♭4: `1 ♭2 ♭3 ♭4 5 ♭6 ♭7`
4. Lydian ♭3: `1 2 ♭3 ♯4 5 6 7`
5. Mixolydian ♭2: `1 ♭2 3 4 5 6 ♭7`
6. Lydian Augmented ♯2: `1 ♯2 3 ♯4 ♯5 6 7`
7. Locrian ♭♭7: `1 ♭2 ♭3 4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭♭7`

**Modes of Major Scale**

1. Ionian: `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`
2. Dorian: `1 2 ♭3 4 5 6 ♭7`
3. Phrygian: `1 ♭2 ♭3 4 5 ♭6 ♭7`
4. Lydian: `1 2 3 ♯4 5 6 7`
5. Mixolydian: `1 2 3 4 5 6 ♭7`
6. Aeolian: `1 2 ♭3 4 5 ♭6 ♭7`
7. Locrian: `1 ♭2 ♭3 4 ♭5 ♭6 ♭7`

**[Modes of Pentatonic Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentatonic_scale#Five_black-key_pentatonic_scales_of_the_piano)**

1. Major Pentatonic Scale: `1 2 3 4 5`
2. Suspended Pentatonic Scale: `1 2 4 5 ♭7`
3. Blues Minor Pentatonic Scale: `1 ♭3 4 ♭6 ♭7`
4. Blues Major Pentatonic Scale: `1 2 4 5 6`
5. Minor Pentatonic Scale: `1 ♭3 4 5 ♭7`

Comment: thank you for the awesome post, a beginner question: when you say, e.g. Lydian Augmented ♯2: 1 ♯2 3 ♯4 ♯5 6 7 - can one replace sharps with flats in this notation so that you have consistency with flats only? i.e. this would be: Lydian Augmented ♯2: 1 ♭3 3 ♭5 ♭6 6 7, is that correct or is there a reason that sometimes sharps are preferred?

Comment: @Amc_rtty, that's a great question. Your suspicion is correct that there's a reason to avoid that notation. While ♭3 and ♯2 are enharmonically the same, they're not the same theoretically. The theoretical difference between them creates a lot of practical differences in our playing. As just one example, the ♭3 will be one of the bottom 2 notes in a chord far more often than the ♯2 will be.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other scales, as requested in the question:

These may have alias names but essentially they are the scale patterns you could derive modes from at each position. I added the interval pattern for reference and an example at the bottom of how to interpret.

- Ionian Mode:     [2,2,1,2,2,2,1]
- Ionian ♯6♭2♭3:   [1,2,2,2,3,1,1]
- Ionian ♯6♭2:     [1,3,1,2,3,1,1]
- Ionian ♭5♯2:     [3,1,1,1,3,2,1]
- Ionian ♯6♭3:     [2,1,2,2,3,1,1]
- Ionian ♯2♭6:     [3,1,1,2,1,3,1]
- Ionian ♯6♭5:     [2,2,1,1,4,1,1]
- Ionian ♯6:       [2,2,1,2,3,1,1]
- Ionian ♯5♯6:     [2,2,1,3,2,1,1]
- Ionian ♯2:       [3,1,1,2,2,2,1]
- Ionian ♯1♭3:     [1,1,2,2,2,2,2]
- Ionian ♯2♯6:     [3,1,1,2,3,1,1]
- Ionian ♭5♭6:     [2,2,1,1,2,3,1]
- Ionian ♭2♭5:     [1,3,1,1,3,2,1]
- Ionian ♯5♯2:     [3,1,1,3,1,2,1]
- Ionian ♭2:       [1,3,1,2,2,2,1]
- Ionian ♯5♭2:     [1,3,1,3,1,2,1]
- Ionian ♭5:       [2,2,1,1,3,2,1]
- Ionian ♯1♭5:     [1,2,1,1,3,2,2]
- Ionian ♭2♭♭3:    [1,1,3,2,2,2,1]
- Ionian ♭5♭6♯1:   [1,2,1,1,2,3,2]
- Ionian ♭6♯1:     [1,2,1,2,1,3,2]
- Ionian ♭6:       [2,2,1,2,1,3,1]
- Ionian ♯1♯2♭6:   [2,1,1,2,1,3,2]

Some alternate representations that you might be more familliar with:
(Note: i can convert all of them to any format if you like)

```
Ionian Mode:
 T   T   S   T   T   T   S   =  tone/semitone
[2,  2,  1,  2,  2,  2,  1]  =  intervals
[0,  2,  4,  5,  7,  9, 11]  =  pitch degrees
[C,  D,  E,  F,  G,  A,  B]  =  pitch classes from 'C' ie. C Ionian Mode
[1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7]  =  scale degrees
 ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^   ^
 |   |   |   |   |   |   Locrean
 |   |   |   |   |   Aeolian
 |   |   |   |   Mixolydian
 |   |   |   Lydian
 |   |   Phrygian
 |   Dorian
 Ionian
```

Answer (score 0):

also found these scales (prime scales i think they're called) that are unique and you can get modes off.. if anyone knows any names you can add them in.

I have alot more but these were 7 notes with less than 4 fret gap and 4 notes in a row.

they are all different patterns and don't overlap with each other so there's a bit to try (about 20 scales x7 modes = 140 total approximately)

- `0 1 2 4 5 7 8`
  `C C# D E F G G#`
- `0 1 3 4 5 7 8`
  `C C# D# E F G G#`
- `0 1 2 4 6 7 8`
  `C C# D E F# G G#`
- `0 1 2 4 5 6 9`
  `C C# D E F F# A`
- `0 1 2 4 5 7 9`
  `C C# D E F G A`
- `0 1 3 4 5 7 9`
  `C C# D# E F G A`
- `0 1 2 4 6 7 9`
  `C C# D E F# G A`
- `0 1 3 4 6 7 9`
  `C C# D# E F# G A`
- `0 2 3 4 6 7 9`
  `C D D# E F# G A`
- `0 1 2 5 6 7 9`
  `C C# D F F# G A`
- `0 1 3 5 6 7 9`
  `C C# D# F F# G A`
- `0 1 2 4 5 8 9`
  `C C# D E F G# A`
- `0 1 2 4 6 8 9`
  `C C# D E F# G# A`
- `0 1 3 4 6 8 9`
  `C C# D# E F# G# A`
- `0 1 2 5 6 8 9`
  `C C# D F F# G# A`
- `0 1 2 4 6 8 10`
  `C C# D E F# G# A#`
- `0 1 3 4 6 8 10`
  `C C# D# E F# G# A#`
- `0 1 3 5 6 8 10`
  `C C# D# F F# G# A#`

On a guitar fretboard:

```
    0 1 2 4 5 7 8 
    C C# D E F G G# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |
    A  | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X|
    D X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|
    G X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |
    B  |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | |
    E X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 4 5 7 8 
    C C# D# E F G G# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|
    A  | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X|
    D  |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X|
    G X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |
    B  |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | |
    E X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X|X| | | |X|X| |X|
    
    0 1 2 4 6 7 8 
    C C# D E F# G G# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |
    A  | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X|
    D X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|
    G X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|
    B  |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | |
    E X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X|X| | | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 2 4 5 6 9 
    C C# D E F F# A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |
    D X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|
    G  | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X|
    B  |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| |
    E X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X|X| | |X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 2 4 5 7 9 
    C C# D E F G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |
    D X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |
    B  |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |
    E X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 4 5 7 9 
    C C# D# E F G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    A X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |
    D  |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |
    B  |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |
    E X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    
    0 1 2 4 6 7 9 
    C C# D E F# G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |
    D X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|
    B  |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 4 6 7 9 
    C C# D# E F# G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    A X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |
    D  |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|
    B  |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    
    0 2 3 4 6 7 9 
    C D D# E F# G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|
    A X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |
    D X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |
    G X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|
    B  |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| |
    E X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|X| |X|X| |X| | |X| |X|X|
    
    0 1 2 5 6 7 9 
    C C# D F F# G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E  |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    D X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|
    B  |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |
    E  |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 5 6 7 9 
    C C# D# F F# G A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E  |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    A X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |
    D  |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X|
    G X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|
    B  |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |
    E  |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| | |X|X| |X|
    
    0 1 2 4 5 8 9 
    C C# D E F G# A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|
    D X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|
    G  |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| |
    B  |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| |
    E X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X|X| | |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 2 4 6 8 9 
    C C# D E F# G# A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|
    D X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|
    G  |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X|
    B  |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |
    E X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 4 6 8 9 
    C C# D# E F# G# A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|
    A X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|
    D  |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X|
    G  |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X|
    B  |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |
    E X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| | |X|X| |X|
    
    0 1 2 5 6 8 9 
    C C# D F F# G# A 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E  |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    A X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|
    D X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|
    G  |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X|
    B  |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| |
    E  |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| | |X|X| |X|X| | |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 2 4 6 8 10 
    C C# D E F# G# A# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |
    A  |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X|
    D X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|
    G  |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X|
    B  |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|
    E X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|X| |
    
    0 1 3 4 6 8 10 
    C C# D# E F# G# A# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|
    A  |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X|
    D  |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X|
    G  |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X|
    B  |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|
    E X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|
    
    0 1 3 5 6 8 10 
    C C# D# F F# G# A# 
       |    ·   ·   ·   ·     :     ·   ·
    E  |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|
    A  |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X|
    D  |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X|
    G  |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X|
    B  |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|
    E  |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X|X| |X| |X| |X|X| |X|
```

Comment: uh, help! my content got converted to chords.. how do i prevent that?

Comment: The problem was that you indented, which gets treated like code. I've put in a fix.

Comment: Your table would take up a whole lot less space if it were made more universal (less guitar-centric) and didn't repeat over multiple octaves.

Comment: @Theodore yeah I just thought it would be easier for people to visualize. I mistakenly assume everything is in relation to guitar. I'll add the list above it, can also delete the fretboards though if that's what we want

Answer (score -2):

I started thinking about Modes as being the DEGREES of the GIVEN scale,in which ea⁰ch scale has it's own MODE Names. Saying this to another musician gives each scale which there are many combinations of notes combined to achieve each scale, to me gives value to ALL scales not just the immediate thought of one, the Major 7th Scale group.